# Cloudfoundry + SpringData + MongoDB...can't deploy

Tags: cloud-foundry, vmc, spring-data-mongodb

I have a simple project based on Spring Data and MongoDB. When I deploy this project to the cloud with the following Spring context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring/cloudfoundry-spring-0.8.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:services.properties" />

<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="gadgetizerApplication" class="it.ids.gadgetizer.GadgetizerApplication">
</bean>

<bean id="gadgetizerService" class="it.ids.gadgetizer.service.impl.GadgetServiceImpl">
    <property name="mongoTemplate" ref="mongoTemplate" />
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender"/>
    <property name="velocityEngine" ref="velocityEngine"/>      
</bean>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="mail.xxx.xxx" />   
    <property name="username" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="port" value="2525"/>
</bean>

<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
  <property name="velocityProperties">
     <value>
      resource.loader=class
      class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
     </value>
  </property>
```

```
<beans profile="development">
    <mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="${mongo.dbname}" host="${mongo.host}" port="${mongo.port}" />
</beans>

<beans profile="cloud">
    <cloud:mongo-db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" service-name="${mongo.cloud.service_name}" />
</beans>
```

It fails with:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lan
.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:110)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
        ... 68 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:123)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.(MongoTemplate.java:196)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.(MongoTemplate.java:185)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
        ... 70 more
Stopping Tomcat because the context stopped.
```

It was working one month ago. What's changed in API?

Thanks

Comment: The problem was the runtime jar user. I was using cloudfoundry-runtime-0.8.1 while the latest is 0.8.2. Solved.

Comment: I am receiving errors for connecting to socket to my mongodb when I push it. Do I have to add a cloud foundry dependency?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue seem to be the runtime jar. Please try to use the latest cloudfoundry-runtime.